# Batch sanitize arguments

Tags: batch-file, escaping, sanitization

I have the following script snippet:

```
if not {%2}=={} (
    if not {%3}=={} (
        "%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" -x -e %2 -p %3 -D "%~dp1"" "%~f1"
    )
)
```

I get an error if I use a closing bracket for an input:

```
C:\>script.bat ).txt
```

The output follows:

```
"test"" can not be processed syntactically at this point.

C:\>        "d:\Scripts\OTRTools\otrtool\otrtool.exe" -x -e  -p  -D "C:\"" "C:\)test"
```

Looks like that bracket is closing one of the if-statements and I need to escape it somehow. Is there any possibility to sanitize the input appropriate?

Comment: Try using quotes instead of curly braces.

Comment: Besides using quotes as previous comment suggested, you have an additional quote at this part: `"%~dp1"" "%~f1"`. Remove it this way: `"%~dp1" "%~f1"`. Is your file named ").txt"? That is a bad idea...

Comment: Well I added the additional quote because I had an issue with a backslash. `~dp1` returns an absolute path to a folder including the last backslash, for example `D:\Stuff\ `, so the call looks like  this `"D:\Scripts\OTRTools\otrtool\otrtool.exe" -x -e -p -D "D:\Stuff\" "D:\test.otrkey"`. Since that tool is compiled with gcc-cygwin, I think that backslash is recognized as escape character, because I get an error: "Missing argument: otrkey-file", which suggests, that `"D:\Stuff\" "D:\test.otrkey"` is seen as a single parameter

Comment: Concerning brackets in the filenames - this is not my idea. I noticed this error because I passed a filename like "blabla (1).txt" to my script. `\(\d\)` is a default pattern for many programs to avoid overwriting files. For example that naming happens if Google Chrome downloads a file with a name which already exists in the download folder.

Comment: Thanks for ideas, it works well now. But in the next line of my script there is a same issue with the bracket. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Nope, I am wrong, the error comes from inside of the next script...

Comment: Here's the follower: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34110341/1851290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch code with the fixes applied as suggested by [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) and [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) :

```
if not "%~2" == "" (
    if not "%~3" == "" (
        "%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" -x -e "%~2" -p "%~3" -D "%~dp1" "%~f1"
    )
)
```

It is important to use on string comparison `%~2` instead of just `%2` to avoid getting on execution for example `if not ""second parameter"" == ""` as this would be again a syntax error.

Run `call /?` in a command prompt window for details on `%~2` (second parameter without quotes), `%~dp1` (drive and path of first parameter without quotes) and `%~f1` (file name of first parameter with drive and path without quotes) and `if /?` for details about using conditions in batch files.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is caused by a backslash at the end of the path (as you indicated in your comment), then just remove it:

```
set "myPath=%~dp1"
if "%myPath:~-1%" equ "\" set "myPath=%myPath:~0,-1%"
if not "%~2" == "" (
    if not "%~3" == "" (
        "%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" -x -e "%~2" -p "%~3" -D "%myPath%" "%~f1"
    )
)
```