# Windows Batch: Invoke an exe with fully qualified path containing whitespaces inside of a for operation

Tags: batch-file

Consider the following snippet:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe "%~1" 2^>^&1') do echo %%A
```

The echo works fine if the script is called from a path without whitespaces. To make it work for paths with whitespaces I added quotes around the .exe:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('"%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" "%~1" 2^>^&1') do echo %%A
```

Now my echo outputs the error message `Der Befehl "d:\Scripts\OTRTools\otrtool\otrtool.exe" "test" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.` which means "Bad command or file name". If I invoke that line without `for`

```
"%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" "%~1" 2^>^&1
```

it works fine. Any idea how to fix the for-line?

Comment: do you try with backslashes ? for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('\"%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe\" "%~1" 2^>^&1') do echo %%A

Comment: @Aurelien nope, backslashes don't help

Comment: Do you try with usebackq option ? for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('"%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" "%~1" 2^>^&1') do echo %%A

Comment: Well I have to replace single quotes with back quotes then. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a space between `'` and `"` like `in (' "%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" "%~1" 2^>^&1')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('CALL "%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe" "%~1" 2^>^&1') do echo %%A
```

inserting `call` seems to cure the problem.

Comment: Batch scripting is such a crazy thing - you never know why it works and why not :) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem by writing a batch called hello.bat inside d:\myFolder and another ind c:\Program Files\folder:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('"%~dp0notepad++.exe.lnk" %~1 2^>^&1') do echo %%A
```

I launched hello.bat in both directories and I could reproduce your error by letting "" around %~1 but once I removed them it works for me.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not solve the problem as arguments `%~1` containing whitespaces are split then...

Comment: That's right: `%0` as well as `%1` may contain whitespaces so quoting is mandatory for both parameters.